# PowerShell script for finding the site columns associated with a content type

Tags: powershell, content-type

How to find the site columns associated with a Content Type using PowerShell Script in my SP 2013 Site Collection.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$site = Get-SPSite "http://srvr1:123/sites/HR"   #your URL  
$web = $site.RootWeb

# Get the GUID of your Site Column View_x0020_Access
$guid =$web.Fields["myDocumentCol"].id            # your Site 
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Basic Content Type"] 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ct.Count; $i++) 
{
    Write-Host "inside for loop"
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $ct[$i].Fields.Count; $j++) 
    {
       if ($ct[$i].Fields[$j].id -eq $guid)
       {
           Write-Host $ct[$i].Name " has column"
       }
    }
 }
```

I tried the above code but it didn't work. It gave me index into null Array error.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$site = Get-SPSite "http://srvr1:123/sites/HR"   #your URL  
$web = $site.RootWeb
# Get the GUID of your Site Column View_x0020_Access
$guid =$web.Fields["myDocumentCol"].id            # your Site 
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Basic Content Type"] 
if($ct) 
{
    Write-Host "inside for loop"
    $fieldInUse = $ct.Fields | Where {$_.Id -eq $guid }
    if ($fieldInUse)
    {
        Write-Host $ct.Name " has column"
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get Amals script to work, but used this instead. The real difference is `$ct = $web.AvailableContentTypes`.

```
# Find all content types that use that column type
# This will display all content types and list details if there match for the column

$site = Get-SPSite "http://srvr1:123/sites/HR"
$web = $site.RootWeb

# Get the GUID of your Site Column 
$guid = $web.fields["myDocumentCol"].id
$ct = $web.AvailableContentTypes 

for ($i=0; $i -lt $ct.Count; $i++) 
{
  for ($j=0; $j -lt $ct[$i].Fields.Count; $j++) 
  {
    if ($ct[$i].Fields[$j].id -eq $guid)
    {
      Write-Host $ct[$i].Name " has column"
    }
  }
}
```